# why does nginx give request time out error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I have deployed a rails app with Nginx and puma web server and Sometimes I get following error.

2018/12/13 12:07:04 [info] 25621#0: *156784 client timed out (110: Connection timed out) while waiting for request, client: 10.66.20.55, server: 0.0.0
.0:80

Can you please tell me what is the meaning of this error. Is the puma server is buzy? or nginx is buzy?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, it is not an error, just **[info]**, so don't worry about it.

Looks like client didn't send any request during **keepalive_timeout**, so connection has been closed.

You should warn about **[error]** entries, because errors occur if application really not accessible.